# return Arraylist of generic objects err

Tags: java, generics

I have the next Generic Object:

```
public class A<T> {
    T a;
 .......
}
```

The next interface :

```
public interface SearchA{
........
   public  ArrayList<A> getChildren(A a);
}
```

and I try to implement this interface in the class :

```
public class AGraph implements SearchA{
......
    public ArrayList<A> getChildren (A s)
    {
        .......
        ArrayList<A<String>> list= new ArrayList();
        ....
        return list;
    }
}
```

In this implementation I'm getting an error when I try to return list , because its type is `ArrayList<A<String>>` instead of `ArrayList<A>`. Do I need to make the interface ASearch generic ? (add `<T>` to the class` header ) ? Or I have another option ?

Thanks.

Comment: I would be surprised if `public interface SearchA { ArrayList<A> getChildren(A a); }` actually compiles.

Comment: Actually it does. why it shouldnt ?

Comment: what about `public ArrayList getChildren(A a) {`

Comment: You're using a rawtype on your method. `ArrayList<A>` has a raw `A`. Typically, don't name your classes single letters

Comment: @YCF_L but then when I use the returned object outside of the functions`s scope, I need to cast the objects inside right ?

Comment: @Rogue I didnt name it A, it is just an example..

Comment: Then post your actual code instead of an example with different issues

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. Dont leave out parts of your code. Show us the exact code that gives the error, and the exact error message. Whenever you *leave out* things, you risk that something **important** isnt available to the people you ask for help. That doesnt mean you should show all code you have, but that [mcve] scope.

Comment: @GhostCat - The code that I specified is enough to understand my problem, didnt want to post too much code that isnt relevant.

Comment: Therefore my last sentence: all *relevant* isnt the same as *all* code. That might require that you sit down and write example code that *shows* your problem. Yes, that requires time. But it is always a good exercise. Sometimes I didn't have to ask here, because just that: sitting down and writing the minimal example already showed me the root cause, so I could fix it myself. As said: your "redactions" add doubt.

Comment: @JeyJ I now see you simply have a class named `A`. My suggestion is never to use class names with a single character, those are often used as generic type argument names.

Answer (score 0):

Your method from the interface `SearchA` returns `ArrayList` which contains a raw version of `A`, but in implementation of the actual method, you return `ArrayList` which contains a generic version of `A`.

Therefore, they are not the same and are incompatible.

Quick fix:

```
public interface SearchA {
    public List<A<String>> getChildren(A a);
}

public class AGraph implements SearchA {
    @Override
    public List<A<String>> getChildren(A a) {
        List<A<String>> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        return arrayList;
    }
}
```

*Side-notes:*

1. It is better to use in this case `new ArrayList<>()` not `new ArrayList()` as a latter option would be an unchecked assignment.
2. It is better to use `List` instead of `ArrayList` in return type of the method and when you declare a reference variable.